# How to compare two datagridviews in different forms in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I compare two different `DatagridView`s across different forms in **VB**?

I've tried this code:

```
if rowThere.Cells(addFormCaller.BOMItemCode.ToString).Value.ToString.Equals(rowHere.Cells("colBOMItemCode").Value.ToString) = True _
                    And rowThere.Cells(1).Value.ToString.Equals(rowHere.Cells(1).Value.ToString) = True _
                    And rowThere.Cells(3).Value.ToString.Equals(rowHere.Cells(2).Value.ToString) = True 
               Then    
                   Return True
              Exit For

            Else
                Return False
            End If
```

but still no luck

Comment: If you can get references to both collections bound to each grid, comparing its contents is relatively easy.

Comment: The perfect way would be to use a datatable, and bind it to your grid. The dataset can be declared as a property, which can be accessed by the second form, for comparison.

Comment: You tried the code and still no luck, in what way though?  The results are not what you expect or Object not set to an instance errors?